# Unable to start Eclipse RSE Server, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rse

I have the problem with Eclipse RSE Server. I'm unable to start it on CentOS 6.4 (AMD64). This is the error messages.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)
        at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:161)
        at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:786)
        at org.eclipse.dstore.internal.core.server.ServerAttributes.getHostName(ServerAttributes.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.dstore.core.server.ServerLauncher.init(ServerLauncher.java:643)
        at org.eclipse.dstore.core.server.ServerLauncher.<init>(ServerLauncher.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.dstore.core.server.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:779)
```

I'm using `daemon.pl` with the root user. Tried `server.pl`. but, the same error occurred.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across the same problem and it was solved after adding my server name to the /etc/hosts file with loopback IP.